# Jquery forcing to double click to submit form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Odd issue where I have to double click to submit my form the first time, but after the first time, the form submits after one click!

Here's my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '.error_box_wrapper',
        success:       showResponse
    }; 
    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#edit_group_form').live('submit', function() {
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit
        $(this).ajaxForm(options); 

        // !!! Important !!!
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation
        return false;
    });
}); 
// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {  
    $("#leftside div#groups_container").load('includes/my_groups.php'); 
} 
</script>
```

Here's my form:

```
 echo "<form id='edit_group_form' action='processforms/process_groups.php' method='POST'>";
 echo "<input name='groupid' type='hidden' value='$groupid' />";
 echo "<input name='image' type='hidden' value='$image' />"; 
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='50000000' />"; 
 echo "<table border=0 width=100%' style='border-left-width: 3px;border-left-style: solid;border-left-color: #ccc; margin-bottom:5px;' class='small_text' >";
 echo "<tr><td valign=top align=right NOWRAP>Group Message:</td>";
 echo "<td valign=top align=left><textarea name='groupmessage' cols=32 rows='3'>$groupmessage</textarea></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td valign=top align=right NOWRAP>Group Name:</td><td valign=top align=left><input name='groupname' size='40' value=\"$groupname\"></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td valign=top align=right NOWRAP>Group picture:</td><td valign=top align=left><input name='uploadedfile' type='file' /></td></tr>";
 echo "</table>"; 
 echo "<input type='submit' value='Save' name='submit_edit_group_form'/></td><td align=left><a href='?view=mygroups' class='mybutton' id='cancel_link'><b>Cancel</b></a>";
 echo "</form>";
```

Thinking it might have something to do with .live

Any ideas are greatly appreciated..Thanks

Comment: I'm not trying to modify the standard user experience. I want the user to click on "submit" and it goes through the first time and not have to double click.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of ajaxForm change it for ajaxSubmit. AjaxForm initializes the form as an ajax form which is why you have to click on it a second time.

From what I recall ajaxSubmit uses the same parameters as ajaxForm so you should be able to just swap it.

Comment: Swapped it, but then nothing happens when I click on submit.

Comment: Its hard to tell what might be happening, do you have an action attribute in your form, did you setup your method attribute as post or get? Mind posting your form if that doesn't do the trick?

Comment: Have you tried switching your live event to a standard bind? Maybe the plugin doesn't work right with a live event. Also, depending on your version of jQuery, live may not be supported on a submit event

Comment: Tried Bind, form still didn't submit. I've posted the code for my form. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check firebug's console tab in firefox and see if an ajax request is being submitted?  Maybe the problem is server side.

Comment: Hmmm I'm a bit at a loss, I'm thinking it might be something small... is the path of your action okay? If you were to submit it as a regular form (without the use of jquery) would it submit correctly? If that's not the cause I'm out of ideas, sorry :-/

Comment: No problem, the thing is the form submits ok on a double click, then after the first submit, it works fine with one click! Crazy.

Comment: That is still the case when you change `$(this).ajaxForm(options);` to `$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);` ? That should definitely fix the dbl-click issue.

Comment: When I change it to .ajaxsubmit, nothing happens when I click on submit.

Comment: Ok, played around with it some more. I was wrong, when changed to .ajaxsubmit, the form does go through but not all of my POST variables are being passed to my .php file to process the form and spit out the results.